# How to synchronize ImageIcon in ImageLoader

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, synchronization

I recently started to use multithreading in Java and I've run into a problem I assume is due to missing synchronization.

This is a ImageLoader I wrote:

```
package util;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
                                          
public class ImageLoader extends Thread {

    private String file;
    private ImageIcon icon;
    
    public ImageLoader(String file) {
        this.file = file;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void run() {
        
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(this.file);
        this.icon = icon;
        super.run();
    }
    
    public synchronized ImageIcon returnIcon() {
        return this.icon;
    }

}
```

I use this ImageLoader in my GUI-Class:

```
package gui;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

import util.ImageLoader;

public class HauptGui extends JComponent {

    public HauptGui() {
        initUI();
    }

    private void initUI() {
        
        int bilderAnzahl = 3;
        
        this.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));
        
        JPanel  bilderPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(bilderAnzahl, 1));
        for (int i = 0; i < bilderAnzahl; i++) {
            JLabel jbl = new JLabel();
            ImageLoader loader = new ImageLoader("./Picture.jpg");
            loader.start();
            jbl.setIcon(loader.returnIcon());           
            jbl.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());
            jbl.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 50));
            bilderPanel.add(jbl);
        }
        
        JScrollPane scrPn = new JScrollPane(bilderPanel);
        
        this.add(scrPn);
        
    }
    
}
```

The Problem is that the returnIcon-Method of the ImageLoader gets called before the Thread calls the run-Method, therefore the ImageIcon is still null.

How do I synchronize this?

Comment: The `ImageIcon(String)` constructor does already use asynchronous image loading. So there is no point in moving its execution to a background thread.

Answer (score 1):

No, your problem has nothing to do with synchronization and all to do with simply requesting the image object *before* it has been created. The solution is to get the image object in a call-back, after it has completed its loading. A SwingWorker would work well in this situation, where you get the image object from the SwingWorker in the worker's done method by calling `.get()` on it, or you could use a PropertyChangeListener for your callback.  See [Lesson: Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for the details on how to use SwingWorkers.

For example (code not tested)

```
public class ImageLoader2 extends SwingWorker<BufferedImage, Void> {
    private String path = "";  /// String to resource path
    
    public BufferedImage doInBackground() throws Exception {
        return ImageIO.read(ImageLoader2.class.getResource(path));
    }
    
}
```

and then run it like:

```
ImageLoader2 loader = new ImageLoader2();

loader.addPropertyChangeListener(pce -> {
    if (evt.getNewValue() == SwingWorker.StateValue.DONE) {
        try {
            BufferedImage img = loader.get();
            ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(img);
            
            // use icon here...
            
        } catch catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            // handle exception here
        }
    }
});
loader.execute();
```

Side notes

1. you should almost *never* extend Thread.
2. Don't get the image as a File as you are doing but rather get it as a resource and use `ImageIO.read(...)` to do this
3. The resource path is relative to the class-path, not to the user's directory, and so it will likely be different from the path you use to get the image as a file.